# Slick-slider заужает блоки-слайды

Tags: frontend

Использую на страничке slick-slider. Присвоение блокам слайдам ширины конкретной ничего не дает. Все равно слик их сам масштабирует. Даже если стиль инлайново присваиваю. Чем меньше слайдов отображаю тем уже он их делает.

```js
'use strict';
$(function () {
  $('.slider').slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    speed: 600,
    infinite: false,
  });
});

let previousOpen = 0;

//ХОВАЄМО ВСІ БЛОКИ З ПІДМЕНЮ
$('.main__menu-content.vogneva').hide();
$('.main__menu-content.individual').hide();
$('.main__menu-content.topography').hide();

//функція приховує попередньо відкритий блок підменюшек
function hideMenuItem(num) {
  switch (num) {
    case 1: //VOGNEVA
      $('.main__menu-content.vogneva').hide();
      $('.main__menu-content.vogneva').toggleClass('active');
      break;

    case 2: //INDIVIDUAL
      $('.main__menu-content.individual').hide();
      break;

    case 3: //TOPOGRAPHY
      $('.main__menu-content.topography').hide();
      break;
  }
}

//функція відображає відповідний блок підменю
function showSlideItem(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1: //VOGNEVA
      $('.main__menu-content.vogneva').show();
      break;

    case 2: //INDIVIDUAL
      $('.main__menu-content.individual').show();

      break;

    case 3: //TOPOGRAPHY
      $('.main__menu-content.topography').show();
      break;
  }
}
function menuItemClick(num) {
  if (previousOpen == 0) {
    previousOpen = num;
    showSlideItem(num);
  } else if (previousOpen != num) {
    hideMenuItem(previousOpen);
    previousOpen = num;
    showSlideItem(num);
  } else {
    hideMenuItem(num);
    previousOpen = 0;
  }
}

/*  MOBILE LOGO CLICK */
$('.mobile__logo').click(function (event) {
  $('.mobile__logo, .mobile__menu').toggleClass('active');
});
/*  MOBILE LOGO CLICK */

/* MINI MENU BTN CLICK*/
let miniLogoClicked = true;
$('.mini__btn').click(function (event) {
  $('.mini__btn,.mini__menu').toggleClass('active');
  if (miniLogoClicked == false) {
    $('.mini__btn').attr('src', 'img/compass.png');
    miniLogoClicked = true;
  } else {
    $('.mini__btn').attr('src', 'img/compass_closed.png');
    miniLogoClicked = false;
  }
});
/* MINI MENU BTN CLICK*/
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #444c38; /*OLIVE*/
  margin: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

body h1 {
  color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
body h2 {
  color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

td {
  padding: 0 5px 0;
}

/* *******************HEADER******************** */
.mobile__header {
  display: none;
}
.header {
  background-color: #444c38; /*OLIVE*/

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

  color: #cc9a45; /* LETTERS*/

  padding-top: 10px;

  margin-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo-label {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
}

/*MENU HORIZONTAL*/
.menu__hor {
  border-top: 2px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
}
.menu__hor__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu__hor__list-item {
  width: 200px;
}
.menu__hor__list-link {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  border-right: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu__hor__list-link.active,
.menu__hor__list-link:hover {
  background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
  color: white;
}
/*MENU HORIZONTAL*/
/* *******************HEADER******************** */

/* *******************MOBILE HEADER******************** */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .header {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile__header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .mobile__header-title {
    font-size: 36px;

    padding: 20px 30px 10px 0;
    color: #fafaf6; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile__logo {
    max-height: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
  }

  .mobile__logo-image {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .mobile__menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
    top: -100%;
    z-index: 6;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .mobile__menu.active {
    top: 70px;
  }
  .mobile__menu__hor__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .mobile__menu__hor__list-link {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile__menu__hor__list-link:hover {
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
  }
  .main {
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  .main__menu__list-link {
    border-top: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  }

  #mini {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile__mini {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
    top: 70px;
    background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
    z-index: 4;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-right: 2px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .mobile__mini__menu__list {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .mobile__mini__menu-link {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
    font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mobile__mini.active {
    left: 0;
  }
}
/* *******************MOBILE HEADER******************** */

/*MAIN - MENU*/
.main {
  width: 100%;
}
.main__menu-item {
  border: 2px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 15px 50px 15px;
}
.main__menu-topic {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main__menu-item-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.main__menu-item-link:hover {
  background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
  color: white;
}

/*MAIN - MENU*/

/*MAIN - CONTENT*/
.content {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu__content {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu__table {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu__table td {
  background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
}
.content__menu-item {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0 20px;
  list-style-type: circle;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.content__menu-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
}

.content__menu-link:hover {
  border: 2px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #444c38; /*OLIVE*/
}

/*MAIN - CONTENT*/

.paragraph {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 15px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  background-color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  border: 1px dotted;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px;

  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
}
.paragraph p {
}
.paragraph img {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.paragraph a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.paragraph a:hover {
  color: white;
}
.paragraph li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.my {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.linko {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

/* VIDEO ELEMENT*/
.video__block {
  margin: 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.video__block-frame {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.video__block hr {
  margin: 0;
}

.video__block-descript {
  color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
}
/* VIDEO ELEMENT*/

/* SLIDER */

/* Слайдер */
.slick-slider {
}
/* Слайдер запущен */
.slick-slider.slick-initialized {
}
/* Слайдер с точками */
.slick-slider.slick-dotted {
}
/* Ограничивающая оболочка */
.slick-list {
}
/* Лента слайдов */
.slick-track {
}
/* Слайд */
.slick-slide {
}
/* Слайд активный (показывается) */
.slick-slide.slick-active {
}
/* Слайд основной */
.slick-slide.slick-current {
}
/* Слайд по центру */
.slick-slide.slick-center {
}
/* Клонированный слайд */
.slick-slide.slick-cloned {
}
/* Стрелка */
.slick-arrow {
}
/* Стрелка влево */
.slick-arrow.slick-prev {
}
/* Стрелка вправо */
.slick-arrow.slick-next {
}
/* Стрелка не активная */
.slick-arrow.slick-disabled {
}
/* Точки (булиты) */
.slick-dots {
}
.slick-dots li {
}
/* Активная точка */
.slick-dots li.slick-active {
}
/* Элемент точки */
.slick-dots li button {
} /* Слайдер */
.slick-slider {
}
/* Слайдер запущен */
.slick-slider.slick-initialized {
}
/* Слайдер с точками */
.slick-slider.slick-dotted {
}
/* Ограничивающая оболочка */
.slick-list {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Лента слайдов */
.slick-track {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
/* Слайд */
.slick-slide {
}
/* Слайд активный (показывается) */
.slick-slide.slick-active {
}
/* Слайд основной */
.slick-slide.slick-current {
}
/* Слайд по центру */
.slick-slide.slick-center {
}
/* Клонированный слайд */
.slick-slide.slick-cloned {
}
/* Стрелка */
.slick-arrow {
}
/* Стрелка влево */
.slick-arrow.slick-prev {
}
/* Стрелка вправо */
.slick-arrow.slick-next {
}
/* Стрелка не активная */
.slick-arrow.slick-disabled {
}
/* Точки (булиты) */
.slick-dots {
}
.slick-dots li {
}
/* Активная точка */
.slick-dots li.slick-active {
}
/* Элемент точки */
.slick-dots li button {
}
/* OUR SLIDER*/
.slider {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 70px;
}
.slider .slick-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider .slick-arrow.slick-prev {
  left: 10px;
  background: url('../img/prev.png') 0 0 / 100% no-repeat;
}
.slider .slick-arrow.slick-next {
  right: 10px;
  background: url('../img/next.png') 0 0 / 100% no-repeat;
}
.slider__item {
  max-width: 25%;
}

.slider .slick-dots {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slider .slick-dots li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
/* Активная точка */
.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active {
}
/* Элемент точки */
.slider .slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.slider .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background-color: #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
  outline: none;
}

/* SLIDER */

/* FOOTER MINI  */
.mini {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.mini__btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
}
.mini__btn.active {
  src: url(../img/eye.png);
}

.mini__menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
  bottom: 130px;
  right: -100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.mini__menu.active {
  right: -2px;
}
.mini__menu__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px;
}
.mini__menu__list-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Neucha', sans-serif;
}
.mini__menu__list-link:hover {
  color: white;
}
/* FOOTER MINI  */

/* FOOTER LOGO */
.footer__logo {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.footer__logo-bottom {
  background-color: #5b6750; /*MILITARY 2*/
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #a1a188; /*MILITARY LIGHT*/
}

.footer__logo-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px;
}
/* FOOTER LOGO */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
 <meta name="description" content="Довідкова інформація військової тематики для піхотних підрозділів">
 <title>Infantry Handbook</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Neucha&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
 <!-- MOBILE HEADER -->
 <header class="mobile__header">

  <div class="mobile__menu">
   <ul class="mobile__menu__hor__list">
    <li class="mobile__menu__hor__list-item"><a class="mobile__menu__hor__list-link 
             " href="index.html">ГОЛОВНА</a></li>
    <li class="mobile__menu__hor__list-item"><a class="mobile__menu__hor__list-link
             " href="handbook.html">ДОВІДНИК</a></li>
    <li class="mobile__menu__hor__list-item"><a class="mobile__menu__hor__list-link
             " href="library.html">БІБЛІОТЕКА</a></li>
    <li class="mobile__menu__hor__list-item"><a class="mobile__menu__hor__list-link
                    " href="video.html">ВІДЕОТЕКА</a></li>
    <li class="mobile__menu__hor__list-item"><a class="mobile__menu__hor__list-link
             " href="links.html">ПОСИЛАННЯ</a></li>

   </ul>
   <!-- FOOTER LOGO - TOP -->
   <footer class="footer__logo ">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPt-5LSaCXZ6RyuHXXCCMhA" target="_blank"
     class="footer__logo-link"><img src="img/youtube_logo.png" title="visit our youtube channel"
      alt="youtube logo"></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/634939450672724/" target="_blank"
     class="footer__logo-link"><img src="img/facebook_logo.png" title="visit our facebook group"
      alt="facebook logo"></a>
    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usingbymyself.militaryhandbook"
     target="_blank" class="footer__logo-link"><img src="img/g_play_logo.png" title="Android app"
      alt="Google Play logo"></a>
   </footer>
   <!-- FOOTER LOGO - TOP-->
  </div>

  <div class="mobile__header-title">ДОВІДНИК ПІХОТИНЦЯ</div>
  <div class="mobile__logo">
   <img class="mobile__logo-image" src="img/google2.png">
  </div>

 </header>
 <!-- MOBILE HEADER -->

 <!--HEADER-->
 <header class="header">

  <!-- FOOTER LOGO - TOP -->
  <footer class="footer__logo ">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPt-5LSaCXZ6RyuHXXCCMhA" target="_blank"
    class="footer__logo-link"><img src="img/youtube_logo.png" title="visit our youtube channel"
     alt="youtube logo"></a>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/634939450672724/" target="_blank" class="footer__logo-link"><img
     src="img/facebook_logo.png" title="visit our facebook group" alt="facebook logo"></a>
   <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usingbymyself.militaryhandbook" target="_blank"
    class="footer__logo-link"><img src="img/g_play_logo.png" title="Android app" alt="Google Play logo"></a>
  </footer>
  <!-- FOOTER LOGO - TOP-->

  <div class="logo">
   <img src="img/google2.png" height="8%" width="8%">

   <h1 class="logo-label">ДОВІДНИК ПІХОТИНЦЯ</h1>

  </div>

  <!--NAV-->
  <nav class="menu__hor">

   <ul class="menu__hor__list">
    <li class="menu__hor__list-item"><a class="menu__hor__list-link
        " href="index.html">ГОЛОВНА</a></li>
    <li class="menu__hor__list-item"><a class="menu__hor__list-link
        " href="handbook.html">ДОВІДНИК</a></li>
    <li class="menu__hor__list-item"><a class="menu__hor__list-link
        " href="library.html">БІБЛІОТЕКА</a></li>
    <li class="menu__hor__list-item"><a class="menu__hor__list-link active
               " href="video.html">ВІДЕОТЕКА</a></li>
    <li class="menu__hor__list-item"><a class="menu__hor__list-link
        " href="links.html">ПОСИЛАННЯ</a></li>

   </ul>


  </nav>
  <!--NAV-->
 </header>
 <!--HEADER-->

 <!--MAIN-->
 <main class="main">
  <!--CONTENT-->
  <div class="content ">

   <!-- ************************ВОГНЕВА ПІДГОТОВКА*********************-->
   <a name="1"></a>
   <h1>ВОГНЕВА ПІДГОТОВКА</h1>
   <hr>

   <h3>Зброя</h3>

   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->
   <section class="slider">
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/_eQLFVpOYm4" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">3D модель роботи АК-47</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/ZyajvvsuGcU" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">3D модель роботи АК-47</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/wMIBUIN30yU" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">3D модель роботи M-16, AR-15</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/DARaGrzBdhY" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">3D модель роботи 12,7 х 105 ДШК</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

   </section>


   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->
   <hr>
   <h3>Високоточна стрільба</h3>

   <!--SLIDER-->
   <section class="slider">
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/wzXWTbPhfHU" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Балістичний калькулятор Strelok Pro, ч.1</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/5BeCFcR7Pic" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Балістичний калькулятор Strelok Pro, ч.2</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/3Dh_FEOe7K8" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Стрільба з нестабільних положень. Частина 1</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/hJBeeXfB4mQ" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Стрільба з нестабільних положень. Частина 2</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/7w7V8Qa-h7M" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Стрільба з нестабільних положень. Частина 3</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/kffpk-odiiA" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Стрільба з нестабільних положень. Частина 4</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/CXW1U2uRVBM" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Читання вітру армійськими снайперами, базові навички
      (USAMU)</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->



   </section>
   <!--SLIDER-->
   <!--************************** ВОГНЕВА ПІДГОТОВКА**********************-->


   <!--********************************ІНДИВІДУАЛКА**********************-->
   <a name="2"></a>

   <h1>ІНДИВІДУАЛЬНА ПІДГОТОВКА</h1>
   <hr>
   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->
   <section class="slider">
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/EK0ODFP-d3g" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Тренінг індивідуальної підготовки з автоматом АК-74</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/xkyThs_iuZE" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Габріель Суарез "Бій з автоматом Калашнікова"</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

   </section>
   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->
   <!--*********************ІНДИВІДУАЛКА********************-->

   <!--********************ТОПОГРАФІЯ*********************-->
   <a name="3"></a>

   <h1> ВІЙСЬКОВА ТОПОГРАФІЯ</h1>
   <hr>
   <h3>Теорія</h3>
   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->
   <section class="slider">

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/jgAk67AFPIQ" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Топографічні карти</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

   </section>
   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->

   <hr>
   <h3>ЗАДАЧІ</h3>
   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->
   <section class="slider">
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/NmCCaMvvpVY" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Комплексна задача. Цілевказання за допомогою оберненого
      азимуту
     </p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->
    <div class="slider__item video__block">
     <iframe class="video__block-frame" src="https://youtube.com/embed/vf9sMmUVgIs" allowfullscreen>
     </iframe>
     <hr>
     <p class="video__block-descript">Комплексна задача</p>
    </div>
    <!-- VIDEO ELEMENT -->

   </section>
   <!-- БЛОК ВІДЕО-->

   <!--****************************ТОПОГРАФІЯ***********************-->

  </div>
  <!--CONTENT-->

 </main>
 <!--MAIN-->

 <!--MINI MENU-->
 <footer class="mini">
  <img class="mini__btn" src="img/compass.png" alt="mini button image" width="100%">
  <nav class="mini__menu">

   <ul class="mini__menu__list">
    <li><a class="mini__menu__list-link" href="#1">ВОГНЕВА</a></li>
    <li><a class="mini__menu__list-link" href="#2">ІНДИВІДУАЛКА</a></li>
    <li><a class="mini__menu__list-link" href="#3">ТОПОГРАФІЯ</a></li>

   </ul>
  </nav>

 </footer>
 <!--MINI MENU-->

 <!-- FOOTER LOGO -->
 <footer class="footer__logo footer__logo-bottom">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPt-5LSaCXZ6RyuHXXCCMhA" target="_blank"
   class="footer__logo-link"><img src="img/youtube_logo.png" title="visit our youtube channel"
    alt="youtube logo"></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/634939450672724/" target="_blank" class="footer__logo-link"><img
    src="img/facebook_logo.png" title="visit our facebook group" alt="facebook logo"></a>
  <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usingbymyself.militaryhandbook" target="_blank"
   class="footer__logo-link"><img src="img/g_play_logo.png" title="Android app" alt="Google Play logo"></a>
 </footer>
 <!-- FOOTER LOGO -->

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй команду       variableWidth: true, для слайдера. Тогда он будет брать размеры элементов слайдера из стилей, прописанных в css